# Cannot detect where alert is coming from in Laravel and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I removed the alert from the JavaScript file by deleting the associated if statement. However, the alert is still showing up. I also tried replacing the alert message, but it didn't make a difference. I used the Bash shell to search the entire repository for the same alert message, but I couldn't find anything else related to it except the first one that I had already found.

```
grep -R "you selected over 24 hours" .

 grep -r "you selected over 24 hours" /Users/myname/myrepos/allcode
```

There are 2 more date and time forms. if the time is over 24 hours it shows alert. there's nothing in console, maybe because its server side but the alert should be client side.

I am so confused.

```
 <div style="padding-bottom: 20px">
        {!! Form::input('date', 'departure_date_flight_' . $increment, $fields['departure_date'] ?? null, ['required' => 'required', 'class' => 'date_time', 'increment' => $increment, 'min' => $date, 'max' => '9999-12-31', 'data-type' => 'start', 'linked' => 'arrival_date_flight_' . $increment, 'onchange' => 'handleDateChange(this)']) !!}
        {!! Form::input('time', 'departure_time_flight_' . $increment, $fields['departure_time'] ?? null, ['required' => 'required', 'class' => 'date_time', 'increment' => $increment, 'linked' => 'arrival_time_flight_' . $increment, 'onchange' => 'handleTimeChange(this)']) !!}
    </div>
```

Comment: The "24 hours" bit might be a variable. Try searching the codebase for "you selected over" by itself. For example, you'll find stuff like this in the validation translations: `'The :attribute must not have more than :max items.'`

Answer (score -1):

It might be showing up because of the view cache. Try to clear the view cache first that might solve the problem considering that you have already removed the associated if statement.

Comment: that was the correct answer. thanks.